# android/iphone - Can a background process or service inject code or read variables in a foreground app?

Tags: android, ios, service, code-injection, trojan

I am getting started on Android & iOS development and hence links to relevant resources will also be appreciated, just that I couldn't find anything much relevant.

Case Detail: I have to build an app that holds some critical information in a variable that is created, sent over a ssl-encrypted connection and destroyed. This variable shouldn't be read by any other process on the device. So far, I know of two cases that can happen:

[1] a service or program monitors the foreground app(which here would be my app) and then if it can inject some code(getting the foreground to bind to the rogue service for example) to read off the variable contents in question. I know OS safeguards exist, but are there any proofs out in the wild that demonstrate this ability of injecting code?

[2] a service or program monitors the network connections and logs the data being sent over the wire. Is there a possibility of apps reading network data like this? I know apps exist which can log the amount of data exchanged per app, but I have no clue as to whether they read system log files or actually monitor the connection.
It will be appreciated if details could be provided for both the platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I work only with android, so this is valid for android only:

No, a service cannot inject code in foreground up, due to (at least) 2 reasons:

- Each installed application gets it's own user id, and each process, and their data is protected by the user id. So one process cannot access the memory of another process. So no process can modify the memory either (by inserting code)
- The java bytecode is converted to dalvik code, and stored in a place where only the system process can write. So no other process can inject code by changing the compiled dex files.

That is the protection provided by the system. Of course hackers might find an exploit in a certain library, and using buffer overflow might be able to run some snippet of code, but that's a different story. Also note that the data files of the process are private by default (no other process can see it), but processes could have read access to the code. Which means storing private keys in the code is probably not safe.

Comment: Thanks for demystifying this. And I ain't storing any keys in code for the very reason you talked about, and instead am calculating them whenever needed. Much thanks again. Now I need to wait for a view on the iOS part.